# no se como realizar que no me seleccione una fecha ya selecciona en un campo anterior con datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

soy nuevo, tengo una duda tengo dos campos donde ocupo datepicker, son datos de fecha de entrada y salida, pero lo que quiero es que la fecha de salida no me pueda seleccionar la fecha de entrada. ya hize varios metodos pero no me funcionaron si alguien me podria ayudar profavor.

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta indica que es la respuesta y marcala con un voto a favor, asíle puede servir a los demás usuarios y visitantes.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que eres nuevo, Bienvenido!!! Sería bueno que te pases por tours para saber como preguntar, te irá bien si lo haces.

Como no has colocado el código, ni has dicho lo que has investigado, iniciaré por el principio (valga la redundancia).

Para ver un calendario en forma de popup normal tenemos que poner:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Para no permitir que los días pasados sean seleccionables tenemos que poner lo siguiente:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
});
</script>
```

Espero que esto te sirva.

Suerte!